# How do load FEEDS youtube apis v3 on windows store c#

Tags: c#, windows, youtube, windows-store-apps, youtube-data-api

to show a news feed, music, sports. thanks.

```
 private void loadfeedYoutube()
    {
         string feedUrl="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular";
         var request=new 
         Feed<Video> videoFeed = request.Get<Video>(new Uri(feedUrl));
         printVideoFeed(videoFeed);

            static void printVideoFeed(Feed<Video> feed)
            {
              foreach (Video entry in feed.Entries)
              {
                printVideoEntry(entry);
              }
            }
    }
```

I'm using:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
```

Error: not finding Feed, request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is using myToolkit

```
  private void GetYoutubeChannel(string feedXML)
    {
        try
        {
            SyndicationFeed feed = new SyndicationFeed();
            feed.Load(feedXML);

            List<YoutubeVideo> videosList = new List<YoutubeVideo>();
            YoutubeVideo video;

            foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
            {
                video = new YoutubeVideo();

                video.YoutubeLink = item.Links[0].Uri;
                string a = video.YoutubeLink.ToString().Remove(0, 31);
                video.Id = a.Substring(0, 11);
                video.Title = item.Title.Text;
                video.PubDate = item.PublishedDate.DateTime;

                video.Thumbnail = YouTube.GetThumbnailUri(video.Id, YouTubeThumbnailSize.Large);

                videosList.Add(video);
            }

            MainListBox.ItemsSource = videosList;
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Comment: @ Nathaniel Chen .I has try your code but have error about that line "video.Thumbail..." i using v3. So i just loaded these id,title,pub date but not load thumbnail because error this line.

Answer (score 0):

Lê Thiên Hoàng

You can try to use SyndicationFeed to help you,

check this example, which using Mytoolkit project to implement.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Youtube-Sample-Get-Youtube-e9a3e0be

and you using feedUrl method is an old api which is v2 not v3.

Comment: video.thumbnail =Google.Apis.YouTube.GetThumbnailUri(video.id, YouTubeThumbnailSize.Large);  

    My error is The name 'YouTubeThumbnailSize' does not exist in the current context

    and GetThumbnailUri' does not exist in the namespace 'Google.Apis.YouTube' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @LêThiênHoàng This code you wrote are Youtube.v3, not i said v2 feedUri method. 
Youtube Api version2 don't need any reference Api, Only access by RESTFul.


Do you tried "Mytoolkit" above?

Answer (score 0):

@Lê Thiên Hoàng

using http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html to generate you want to get.

if you want get music popular, then your RESTFul Api link is:
[http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed/-/{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat}Music?alt=rss](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed/-/%7Bhttp://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat%7DMusic?alt=rss)

But I recommend if you can, using Youtube API Version3, is better and easier to get different category video.

Comment: I click this your link then the pages will show "Invalid category filter ''.What's that.

Comment: @LêThiênHoàng will, i found that problem yesterday.
You need replace {} to unicode url like:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_viewed/-/%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fgdata.youtube.com%2Fschemas%2F2007%2Fcategories.cat%7DMusic?alt=rss

Because parse feed is very annoying,
so I decide changing to V3 api...easier to use and filte, and I'm writing a sample.

Maybe can complete today.

Comment: THanks, your app just loaded title,pub date... but i want add to sum viewer and who has uploaded.
ex:item.Title.Text; When i writen throught "item." and I'm not finding "count view"or people has upload  . English is little bad.